# How to convert base64 to image in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfimage

I am trying to convert a base64 string into an image in ColdFusion, but it is not working. From what I have read, this can be done with the ImageReadBase64 function:

```
<cfset myImage = ImageReadBase64("/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA..............")>
```

So I tried retrieving a base64 image string from my database:

```
<cfquery name="GetSignImage" datasource="#application.ds#">
      select SIGNIMGBINARY 
      from   T_APPT_sign
      where  CHECKINID ='#CHECKINID#'
</cfquery>

<cfif GetSignImage.SIGNIMGBINARY neq "">
    <cfimage source="#ImageReadBase64(GetSignImage.SIGNIMGBINARY)#" name="signImage" action="resize" width="65%" height="55%">
    <cfimage source="#signImage#" action="writeToBrowser">
</cfif>
```

But I get this error:

*The Base64 data is not in proper format. Data should be in the format understood by the <img> tag in HTML, which is "data:image/jpg;base64,[base64 data]"*

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Ist he Bas64 encoded string returned by the databse complete? Maybe the DB only returned the first 4000 bytes or so.

Comment: i get this error 
The Base64 data is not in proper format. Data should be in the format understood by the &lt;img&gt; tag in HTML, which is "data:image/jpg;base64,[base64 data]"

Comment: First check if the source you are specifying is an image. Like this:
`<cfdump var = "#isImage(ImageReadBase64(GetSignImage.SIGNIMGBINARY))#">`
It will help you find the issue.

Comment: hello, no changes... it still gv me Error Occurred While Processing Request
The Base64 data is not in proper format. Data should be in the format understood by the &lt;img&gt; tag in HTML, which is "data:image/jpg;base64,[base64 data]"

Comment: Error messages belong [in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37249390/edit) so they are more visible.